# Why is my Python code giving only the half of the json to my PHP?

Tags: php, python, communication

So, yeah.

I'm using Visual Studio Code, Python 3.8.0 and XAMPP.

I don't know why it is like it is. I tried figuring it out for hours, but I didn't find anything neither I fixed it.

My Python-Output looks like this >>>> `python main.py DBOS.19b DBOS.19a` >> `print(json.dumps(currentdata))`:

```
[
    [],
    [
        ['Mittwoch', '3', '+Soend (Irm)', 'E', '0.88', 'DBOS.19a', 'Soend', '', ''],
        ['Mittwoch', '4', '+Soend (Irm)', 'E', '0.88', 'DBOS.19a', 'Soend', '', ''],
        ['Mittwoch', '5', '+Goepp (Irm)', 'E', '1.17', 'DBOS.19b', 'Goepp', '', ''],
        ['Mittwoch', '6', '+Goepp (Irm)', 'E', '1.17', 'DBOS.19b', 'Goepp', '', '']
    ],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
]
```

While my PHP-Output looks like this >>>> `$main = exec("python main.py DBOS.19b DBOS.19a");` >> `var_dump($main);`:

```
string(180) "
[
    [],
    [
        ["Mittwoch", "3", "+Soend (Irm)", "E", "0.88", "DBOS.19a", "Soend", "", ""],
        ["Mittwoch", "4", "+Soend (Irm)", "E", "0.88", "DBOS.19a", "Soend", "", ""]
    ],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
]
"
```

Comment: The main difference is the environment and the user that is running the python script.  But I don't know what `DBOS.19b DBOS.19a` is.

Comment: These are my Arguments when I call the Python-Script. But why is it just showing 2 instead of 4 entries in the json? I don't get it for real.

My main.py: https://pastebin.com/C8fc7rfG
My index.php: https://pastebin.com/7QQzCrRE

I am really wondering why those entries ain't identical.